# Very basic understanding of machine learning from statistics point of view

Tags: machine-learning, notation

I don't know if this is the right place, but I have a general question about machine learning from a statistics point of view.

I know bits and pieces, but I don't get the overall picture. Add to that the fact that my math skills are pretty limited and I only have a basic grasp of statistics.

Here's what I think I know:

1. Our data comes from some unknown distribution $P(X,Y)$. Let's take
   the *Iris* data set. Each of the 4 features follows the same unknown distribution (i.i.d. assumption), even though in reality this may not be true.

   So we have four unknown distribution $A,B,C,D$. This means, for the
   *Iris* data set, our unknown distribution would be $P((A,B,C,D), Y)$,
   where $A,B,C,D$ are combined as $X$ by multiplying them. We can do
   this, because they are i.i.d.

   And $Y$ also follows some unknown distribution.

   So if I have the following training instance:

   $(1,2,3,4) : 1$ it means it's a concrete realisation of the random
   variables $A,B,C,D$ and $Y$. in this case, the instance has the class label 1.

   If we knew the distributions, we could just calculate the total probability by multiplying the individual probabilities.
2. Some machine learning algorithms try to estimate $P(X,Y)$ from data,
   by using MLE or MAP. $P(X,Y) = P(Y|X)P(X)$ or $P(X|Y)P(Y)$.
   MLE estimates $P(Y|X)$ (estimating $P(X)$ is not necessary, I guess) and MAP estimates $P(X|Y)P(Y)$.

   Algorithms that use MLE or do something completely different,
   without probabilities (like SVM) are discriminative, the others are
   generative.

   Generative algorithms always use the Bayes Theorem.

   Now the notation here really confuses me: The way I understand it, MLE estimates $P(D;\theta)$, where $\theta$ is some unknown but fixed value. In our case, $\theta$ is our machine learning model, the hypothesis. Usually, we would write $P(D|\theta)$, but since $\theta$ is not a random variable, we use the other notation.

   So if I use logistic regression or a decision tree, MLE would estimate $P(\mathrm{Data};\mathrm{SomeConcreteLogisticRegressionFunction})$ or $P(\mathrm{Data};\mathrm{SomeConcreteDecisionTree})$

   What confuses me most, I think, is the notation: MLE estimates $P(Y|X)$ which makes sense: I want to know the most probable label. In this notation $P(D|\theta)$, D would be the label and $\theta$ is our training data?

   For logistic regression, I have also seen $P(Y|X;\theta)$, which I think means: Probability of the label, given our training data and our learning model.

   Or is MLE only used for getting a value for $\theta$ from the data ($P(D|\theta)$) and $P(Y|X;\theta)$ is something different?

**EDIT**

So as per the comment, I guess this makes sense: $P(D|\theta)$ or $P(D;\theta)$ means I estimate $\theta$ from the data set.

in our case, the data set is X. So $P(D|\theta)$ is $P(X|\theta)$. How does the $Y$ come into the notation?

Comment: Don't we need context to talk about notations? $D$ usually represents a dataset containing features and labels, and $\theta$ the model parameters, so $P(D|\theta)$ is usually the likelihood function.

Comment: Okay, makes sense. So that means, that we estimate $\theta$ from the data set, which is indicated by $P(D|\theta)$ ?

Comment: $P(D|\theta)$ indicates the likelihood of having dataset $D$ given a model parameterized by $\theta$. MLE says that the optimal $\theta$ maximizes the likelihood.

Comment: @doubllle could you provide references or links to those books?

Comment: @doubllle I'm sorry, but what would really help me is to get an answer for my question. You dont think I have look at books and scripts and blog posts enough? But obviously, it didn't help me. Because my point is that the notation is not clear to me.

Comment: [Machine Learning: A Probabilistic Perspective](https://www.amazon.com/Machine-Learning-Probabilistic-Perspective-Computation/dp/0262018020) and [Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387310732)

Comment: @user3813234 for your update, why don't you include $Y$ in the dataset? I guess the context is supervised learning, and you'll always have feature-label pairs as your dataset. And also, the notations could be different during training stage and inference stage. So I think context is important.

Comment: @doubllle you are right, supervised learning. Well, I guess the reason is the damned notation. My understanding now is this: MLE estimates P(Y|X), which means: Given an input X, what is the most probable label Y? How does this relate to this notation: $P(D;\theta)$? According to you, D is Y|X?? That's the whole point of my second question. How do these notations relate? It seem to me that it should be obvious to me that $P(Y|X)$ and $P(D|\theta)$ and $P(D;\theta)$ and $P(Y|X;\theta)$ are all the same, but I don't see how.